# How to loop through a nested list, compare the first element to another list, and then append to a new list?

Tags: python, list, loops, deep-learning, nested-lists

I am trying to create three separate lists (training, testing, and validation) for a CNN. 
 I have three lists (train_data, test_data, val_data) that ONLY contain the image names

```
train_data = ["img_1.png", "img_2.png"] 
test_data = ["image_3.png", "img_4.png"] 
val_data = ["img_5.png", "img_6.png"]
```

I have another nested list that contains all the images names and associated labels for a deep learning model

```
image_annotations = [['img_1.png', 432, 662, 554, 749, 'class'], 
    ['img_1.png', 647, 456, 754, 594, 'class'], ['img_2.png', 598, 659, 897, 
    302, 'class']]
```

I would like to run a loop through my `image_annotations` list and if the image name is the same as an image name in my `train_data, test_data, val_data` lists then I want to append the four following numbers and class name to that list. The `image_annotations` list has multiple listings of the same image but with different bounding box numbers.
I imagine that this might be quite simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your question implies that you'll end up having a list as such : `train_data=["img_1.png", "img_2.png",  432, 662, 554, 749,598, 659, 897, 302 ]`, is this what you want ?

Comment: @Rphad good catch, no that's not the final format I need. the final list I need is something like train_data = [["img_1.png", 546, 789, 987, 567, 'class'], ["img_1.png", 435, 546, 768, 459, 'class'], ["img_2.png", 234, 456, 763, 946, 'class']]

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

```
train_data_full = []
for t_d in train_data:
    for i_a in image_annotations:
        if t_d in i_a:
            train_data_full.append(i_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the answer to your question

```
train_data = ["img_1.png", "img_2.png"] 
test_data = ["image_3.png", "img_4.png"] 
val_data = ["img_5.png", "img_6.png"]
image_annotations = [['img_1.png', 432, 662, 554, 749, 'class'],['img_1.png', 647, 456, 754, 594, 'class'],['img_2.png', 598, 659, 897, 302, 'class']]
my_lists = [train_data, test_data, val_data]
for im in image_annotations:
    for k in my_lists:
        if im[0] in k:
            for i in range(1,5):
                k.append(im[i])

for list in my_lists:
    print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
train_data = ["img_1.png", "img_2.png"] 
test_data = ["image_3.png", "img_4.png"] 
val_data = ["img_5.png", "img_6.png"]

image_annotations = [['img_1.png', 432, 662, 554, 749, 'class'], 
    ['img_1.png', 647, 456, 754, 594, 'class'], ['img_2.png', 598, 659, 897, 
    302, 'class']]

# get a maping with all the img names and their value
d = {}
for e in image_annotations:
    d.setdefault(e[0], []).append(e)


# set new values to data variables accordding to dict d
for l in train_data, test_data, val_data:
    l[:] = [e for i in l for e in d.get(i, [i])]


print(train_data)
print(test_data)
print(val_data)
```

output:

```
[['img_1.png', 432, 662, 554, 749, 'class'], ['img_1.png', 647, 456, 754, 594, 'class'], ['img_2.png', 598, 659, 897, 302, 'class']]
['image_3.png', 'img_4.png']
['img_5.png', 'img_6.png']
```